# Import Excel sheet to Mongodb Database with column mapping

Tags: php, import, import-from-excel, pipedrive-api

Importing Excel sheet to Mongodb Database with Column Mapping.I need a PHP plugin similar to pipedrive import data please suggest if there is any.

Answer (score -1):

You can create it on your own. I have developed this kind of code that reads data from Mysql DB and put it in mongodb, its code is:

```
$collection = $db->createCollection("emp_details");
$collection->createIndex(array('email' => 1));

$getAllEmp = "select first_name, last_name, position, email, office, start_date, age, salary from datatables_demo";
$resAllEmp = mysqli_query($conn, $getAllEmp);

$data   = array();
$count  = 1;
if(mysqli_num_rows($resAllEmp) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resAllEmp))
    {
        $data['_id']        = new MongoId();
        $data['emp_id']     = $count; 
        $data['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $data['last_name']  = $row['last_name'];
        $data['position']   = $row['position'];
        $data['email']      = $row['email'];
        $data['office']     = $row['office'];
        $data['start_date'] = $row['start_date'];
        $data['age']        = $row['age'];
        $data['salary']     = $row['salary'];
        $data['project']    = array('Project1', 'Project2', 'Project3');
        $data['password']   = md5('12345');

        if($collection->insert($data))
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Use above code and modify it by removing the Mysql part and add csv read part to it and it works fine.